# Adding new scopes to Google suite projects (apps)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have our Google App which is already published and used by our customers now. Wanted to add 2 new scopes.
We want to make sure that we do this seamlessly without either publishing the app or without asking each customer to reinstall.

Is there any way to achieve this? If not, what steps/process we need to follow.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update add-on code:

In case you just need to update the code, use [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on#update_published_add-on_code):

[image]

As you can see, **users don't need to reinstall the add-on, but if you added additional scopes, they need to authorize the new scopes**.

#### Update Marketplace listing:

In case you also need to make changes to your add-on Marketplace listing, follow [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/manage-app-listing#update_your_app_listing):

[image]

Please take into account that you might need to submit a new request for OAuth verification depending on the new OAuth scopes you want to add:

> **Note**: If you add new OAuth scopes, you might need to file a new request for OAuth verification. If you update your listing to use the new scopes before they’re approved, users are shown the unverified app screen. Quota limits are applied until the new OAuth verification request is approved. To learn more, see [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).

#### Reference:

- [Update published add-on code](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on#update_published_add-on_code)
- [Update your app listing](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/manage-app-listing#update_your_app_listing)